# Remove list from lists in list if length

Tags: r, list, if-statement, remove-if

I have this list:

```
a <- list(list(c("sam1", "control"), c("sam1", "latanoprost free acid", "GSM6683", "GSM6684"), c("sam1", "prostaglandin F2alpha", "GSM6687", "GSM6688")), list(c("sam2", "control"), c("sam2", "latanoprost free acid", "GSM6681", "GSM6682"), c("sam2", "prostaglandin F2alpha", "GSM6685", "GSM6686")))
```

I'd like to remove the elements (lists), which length are less than three (<3). I tried double lapply to get a[[i]][[j]] and <- NULL, but I got lists only with NULL.
Like this:

```
b <- lapply(seq(length(a)),function(i){
  lapply(seq(length(a[[1]])),function(j){
    if(length(a[[i]][[j]]) < 3) {a[[i]][[j]] <- NULL}
  })
})
```

Thank you for any help...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
lapply(a, function(x) x[sapply(x, length) >= 3])
```

or

```
lapply(a, Filter, f = function(x) length(x) >= 3)
```

Comment: +1 Thank you, both works perfectly. I'll use the second one, it's very nice. THX.